# Replacing ^^J with ^^J%% within DocTeX's first pass of a DocTeX document?

Tags: package-writing, dtx

## Question

Is it possible to perform text replacement during the first pass of a document by DocTeX ? Specifically, how can I replace `^^J` with `^^J%%` in a `\edef`'d macro ?

## Background

I had recently noticed that I was repeating the [copyright notice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468573/14593) no less then three times in my DocTeX files, which is not especially DRY. I've managed to reduce this to one `\edef`'d preamble, `\metadata`.

```
\edef\metadata{================================================================^^J
               \jobname\space(Version\space\fileversion\space-\space\filedate)}^^J
               ================================================================^^J}
```

I can expand this into a `\declarepreamble\metatext...\endpreamble` block by wrapping the `\declarepreamble` into another definition and delaying it's expansion as follows :

```
\def\expandamble{\declarepreamble\metatext}
\expandafter\expandamble\metadata
\endpreamble
```

Which DocTex expands into the following in the output files. This triggers errors in other documents that use the generated style/class files since `====` is no macro definition.

```
%%==================================
PACKAGE (Version 0.0 - 2019/01/15)
==================================
```

Ideally `\MetaPrefix`, that is `%%`, should be prepended to each line as follows.

```
%%==================================
%%PACKAGE (Version 0.0 - 2019/01/15)
%%==================================
```

Clearly it is only prepended to the first line as the expansion I'm performing unpacks `\metadata` as a single line of text and not as 3 lines. I'm not sure how to handle this expansion properly and was hoping for some help.

## Homework

David Carlisle provides the following snippet in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213950)

```
\def\replace#1#2#3{%
 \def\tmp##1#2{##1#3\tmp}%
   \tmp#1\stopreplace#2\stopreplace}
\def\stopreplace#1\stopreplace{}
```

It seems however that one may not pop `\metadata` in as the first argument.
That is calling the macro

```
\replace{\metadata}{^^J}{^^J\MetaPrefix} % This result should be assigned to a new macro/preamble \metatext
```

produces the following error, complaining that I'm not in a document environment just yet, nor will I ever be as this is during the first pass by DocTeX.

```
! LaTeX Error : Missing \begin{document}.
```

## Update

Incorporating the comment from Phelype Oleinik I get the following code

```
\def\expandamble{\declarepreamble\metatext}
\expandafter\expandamble\expandafter\replace\expandafter{\metadata}{^^J}{^^J\MetaPrefix}
\endpreamble
```

and the following error

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \metatext. 
  <to be read again> 
                     1
```

## Note

This is related to another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468685/14593) I have open at the moment. I'm trying to solve it by breaking it down into it's component issues.

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but it looks like that David's `\replace` command replaces without expansion, so it can't find any occurrence of `^^J` in the single token `\metadata`. I think you'd have to expand `\metadata` first: `\expandafter\replace\expandafter{\metadata}{^^J}{^^J\MetaPrefix}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thanks for the input, I tried it and updated the question to reflect the output. I'll try play around with the `\expandafter`s if I have any luck I'll report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get terminal output of

```
================================================================
bb280 (Version v1.2 - yesterday) 
================================================================

%%================================================================
%%bb280 (Version v1.2 - yesterday) 
%%================================================================
%%
```

from

```
\makeatletter
\def\fileversion{v1.2}
\def\filedate{yesterday}

\def\metadata{================================================================\newline
              \jobname\space(Version\space\fileversion\space-\space\filedate) \newline
              ================================================================\newline}

{\def\newline{^^J}\xdef\metadataA{\metadata}}
{\def\newline{^^J\@percentchar\@percentchar}\xdef\metadataB{\@percentchar\@percentchar\metadata}}

\typeout{\metadataA}

\typeout{\metadataB}


\stop
```

There is no need to put in `^^J` originally if you want to replace it, use something easier to redefine and define that to be `^^J` when you need it.

Comment: Oh that is quite elegant, I hadn't though of substituting, rather then replacing, the new lines. Thanks once again for the help. (P.S. I can't recall If I replied the other day but I did read your responses to my questions about where you work, thanks. I think I tried keeping the responses to a minimum in case the thread got permanently stored on Stack Exchanges chat).